# Does MSVC mishandle the linkage of class-scoped statics with integral constant initializers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using C++03:

In foo.h:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        // Declare integral static constant with an initializer
        static const int some_constant = 42;
};
```

In foo.cc:

```
// Define and reserve storage for Foo::some_constant
const int Foo::some_constant;
```

In bar.cc:

```
#include <foo.h>
// stuff that uses Foo::some_constant;
```

It has long been my understanding that the above is the correct way to do this. A class-scoped static is permitted to have an initializer if it is of integral type and the initializer is a constant expression. Similarly, you must always declare storage for a static in exactly one translation unit (mod templates, but lets ignore that).

However, MSVC 2010, 2012, and apparently 2013 RC all fail to link a program containing both foo.cc and bar.cc, claiming that Foo::some_constant is multiply defined.

Have I misunderstood something and done this wrong, or is VC in error here? If the latter, does anyone have a reference to a bug report or something similar?

Please don't tell me to move the initializer into the .cpp file. I know I can do that, but for now I'm more interested in this from a language rules and compiler quality-of-implementation standpoint, rather than workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; the way you wrote it is correct and VS is wrong.

However, VS probably gets it wrong because you haven't disabled compiler extensions. If you compile with the `/Za` flag then it should work correctly.

Alternatively, you can wrap the definition in a preprocessor `#if` block:

```
#if !_MSC_EXTENSIONS
// Define and reserve storage for Foo::some_constant
const int Foo::some_constant;
#endif
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a pointer to any documentation that explains which extension it is that causes this behavior, and why it is considered 'good'?

Comment: @acm I don't think it is a good extension. I think it's mostly around for legacy reasons (for the same reason VS allows you to bind temporaries to non-const lvalue references).

Answer (score 1):

If you use an initializer to initialize a static const member, the declaration outside the class is not needed. For example:

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T , T val>
    struct integral_constant
    {
        typedef T value_type;
        static const T value = val;
    };
}
```

Comment: It's not quite that simple. If you take the address of that member it must have a definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker, can't it handle it the same way it handles taking the address of an inline function?

Comment: @PeteBecker True, but if you are writing a library, you can't really know whether a depending body of code will or will not take the address of the static constant, so it is pretty much required to declare storage, right?

Comment: @MarkRansom - hypothetically it could, but the rule is that the definition is required.

Comment: @acm - it depends on what the documented interface to the library is. If it says that this is a constant and you can't takes its address and you can't pass it by reference, then you don't need a definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker That is a good point about the documentation, but I'd prefer to make mis-use impossible. Sometimes people don't read things as closely as they ought to. It sounds from another answer in this thread that the observed behavior may be a helpful microsoft 'extension' of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC is incorrect base on the C++ standard. The static member `some_constant` in header file is not an definition when included in other CPP. So there shouldn't be multiple symbole defintion. Following is quote from C++ standard (emphasis mine).

> **A declaration is a deﬁnition unless** it declares a function without
>   specifying the function’s body (8.4), it contains the extern speciﬁer
>   (7.1.1) or a linkage-speciﬁcation25 (7.5) and neither an initializer
>   nor a function- body, **it declares a static data member in a class
>   deﬁnition** (9.2, 9.4), it is a class name declaration (9.1), it is an
>   opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), it is a template-parameter (14.1), it
>   is a parameter-declaration (8.3.5) in a function declarator that is
>   not the declarator of a function-deﬁnition, or it is a typedef
>   declaration (7.1.3), an alias-declaration (7.1.3), a using-declaration
>   (7.3.3), a static_assert-declaration (Clause 7), an attribute-
>   declaration (Clause 7), an empty-declaration (Clause 7), or a
>   using-directive (7.3.4).

Answer (score 0):

Move the initialization from the declaration to the definition, i.e. from foo.h into foo.cc.

foo.cc:

```
// Define and reserve storage for Foo::some_constant
const int Foo::some_constant = 42;
```

If both foo.cc and bar.cc `#include "foo.h"` the compiler sees the initialization twice and complains about multiple definitions. foo.h should read

```
class Foo {
public:
    // Declare integral static constant here, initialize outside
    static const int some_constant;
};
```

Comment: As I explicitly stated, I do not want to move it to the .cpp file.

Comment: I concur now, MS VC's behavior doesn't seem to honor the exemptions from ODR stated in paragraph 5 (in ISO 14882:2003). Just learnt about these. Sorry for not reading your question completely.